# Accepting user data into a table

Tags: android

I'm designing an app which will accept user input into a TableLayout . The table has 4 headings . I'm unsure of how to get the data into the table . I have a successfully added a test piece of code but I can only add it once. I've attached the code below.

What I wish to know is how to get this to add more than one line to the table?

```
public void addNew(){
    TableLayout tL = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    TableRow tR = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

    TextView tV = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tV.setTextColor(0xff000000);
    tV.setText("TEST");

    TextView tV2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tV2.setTextColor(0xff000000);
    tV2.setText("TEST");

    TextView tV3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tV3.setTextColor(0xff000000);
    tV3.setText("TEST");

    TextView tV4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    tV4.setTextColor(0xff000000);
    tV4.setText("TEST");

    tR.addView(tV);
    tR.addView(tV2);
    tR.addView(tV3);
    tR.addView(tV4);

    tL.addView(tR);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (/* x rows */)
{
    tL.addView(tR);
}
```

This should work but if you run into an issue with text view id's clashing you can create an array of text views and an array of table rows.  Would make managing and creating them easier as well.

If you make them in an array by doing something like this.

```
TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewCount];

for(int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++) 
{
    textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
}
```

then you would be able to handle individual values by doing something like this.

```
textViewArray[i].setText(/* This stuff */);
```

Comment: If I was to make an array would I be able to read in user data to populate the array ?

Comment: Ok I think I understand . I'll try to get this working . Thanks so much for the help.